# Intellij hot key

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Каким хоткеем можно вызывать такое окно (не <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это окошко называется "Parameter Info" и вызывается комбинацией клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: По поводу правки [описания pyqt5](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/50033): это целиком копипаста, так делать нежелательно. И вообще у описаний меток немного другие цели и наполнение. [tag:android] можно в качестве примера посмотреть. Будет здорово, если вы напишете собственный текст. Подробнее: [Копирование статей из Википедии в описания меток — это плохо](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/138)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Понял. Спасибо.